transferring data between python and MATLAB: how to deal with list of lists?
I did this post in Mathwork as well. But I guess I will benefit also asking it here.
Here is a link to my mathwork community post.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2104821-load-save-python-list-of-list-with-matlab?s_tid=prof_contriblnk
Basically, my issue is I have some cell arrays in my '.mat' data, and they are like landmines. I only know when I step on them. Those cell arrays are converted to list of list in python using the 'mat73' library to load the matfile, but cannot be convert back to matlab cell array when I try to save them with scipy.
I wonder if there are other possible python library that could deal saving list of list. Or if I can save out python object and load them MATLAB with some MATLAB trick.
My data would look something like this:
dat = {'k1':{'k11':[1,2,3],'k12':[[1,2],[1],[2,2]]},'k2': [] ....}

The issue would be to save dat['k1']['k12'] because it is the lists in list are different in length. Except I don't know where this 'k12' would pop up in my actual data, and it is probably a lot more nested than this example.
Any comments are welcomed. And I can try solution in both MATLAB and python. Thanks a lot!
I could avoid this by padding the list of list to the same length within python. The way I padded data is from this post: padding a list of lists to make it equal to the size of the largest list.
I used that method when I created a list of list and wanted to save that to a matfile.
It is still possible but it's just very annoying to do it with the current issue... (where I would have to search for the list of lists if I wantted to pad it.

If your Python data contains only straightforward types like dicts, lists, numeric values and strings - as shown in your example - then you should be able to use JSON to pass the data to MATLAB.
For example, in Python:
import json

dat = {'k1':{'k11':[1,2,3],'k12':[[1,2],[1],[2,2]]},'k2': []}

with open('dat.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dat, f)

and then in MATLAB:
>> dat = jsondecode(fileread('dat.json'))

dat = 

  struct with fields:

    k1: [1×1 struct]
    k2: []

>> dat.k1

ans = 

  struct with fields:

    k11: [3×1 double]
    k12: {3×1 cell}

>> dat.k1.k12

ans =

  3×1 cell array

    {2×1 double}
    {[       1]}
    {2×1 double}

To explore what's in a MATLAB struct and access its contents programmatically, you can use the fieldnames function and the struct.(something) notation.
